# Modify Model structure without changing existing EF 4.x Generated Model in Database First Approach

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, database-first

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Database First approach with EF 4.x. Models are generated with EF 4.x DBContext Generator. Now I want to change model structure but don't want to change existing model because if database is modified I have to generate model again so the changes will be gone. I think it should be done by overriding partial classes but not clear. Is there any example to do it? what is the best way to implement it?

Edit: I have to add some additional validations in some Models, not all. I want to create independent models which overrides the generated classes and in case if EF models are regenerated there is no harm on our customized models.

Comment: if I  undrestand you correctly you want to update certain model class but you do not want it to be erased when you update the whole model

Comment: when you update model update only classes/tables that you think will change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can change the *.tt file for generating objects from model. What do you want to change objects.
2. You can create partial classes like this

   namespace MyProject.Data{
       public partial class User{}
   }

but your partial class should be the same namespace of EF created classes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    [MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
    public partial class User : IEntity
    {
        internal class UserMetadata
        {
            [DisplayName("User Name")]
            public virtual string UserName
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            [DisplayName("First Name")]
            public virtual string FirstName
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            [DisplayName("LastName")]
            public virtual string LastName
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've to change specific models only...so couldn't change template.

Comment: then use second solution and create partial class for specific classes

Comment: How can I change existing property annotations in new class? I've to keep EF generated class also.

Comment: One Quick Question ... Do we need EF *.tt generated Classes? If I'm creating separate viewmodels for each.

Comment: if you create viewmodels than you should not need to partial classes